# Monaco - unregister language feature

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm adding a custom language to monaco like this:

```js
monaco.languages.register({ id: 'someLanguage' });
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('someLanguage', { 
    provideCompletionItems: function () { /* ... */ }
});
```

I'm doing this in a dev environment that hot reloads on changes and thus it's using hot reloading. The same code is run again everytime the content is saved. Causing the code above to be called many times and thus monaco registers again and again the same functions. In this example of completion provider then all my previous providers are kept when a new one is added following the hot reloading of the script.

Do we have any way to unregister a language in order to register it again?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`registerCompletionItemProvider` returns an object with a `dispose` function.
Simply call it to unregister your listener.

```js
const { dispose } = registerCompletionItemProvider( ... )

dispose();
```